# Determining User's Current Location and Placing Marker

Tags: android

I am working on an app that requires the user's current location to be marked on a MapView. I've looked all around the internet, and haven't found anything that works with my code. I've looked at many questions on this site and on other Android tutorial sites/YouTube videos. I have tried getting permission to access fine location and then creating a string with the current latitude and longitude inside it. However, this just doesn't work.

I've tried playing around with the code, but I just can't figure it out. What I want to do is get the user's current location and then place a marker on a MapView that also contains a marker placed at a location. I understand the code, I just don't know a) why it isn't working and b) what I need to do to fix it. I have included the activity's code below.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;


public class fthactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fthactivity);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fthmap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        findViewById(R.id.fthphone).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialContactPhone(" 1234567890");
            }
        });

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fthweb);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.ca/"));
                startActivity(myWebLink);

            }

        });

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 3);
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        GoogleMap mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng fthloc = new LatLng(51.036585, -114.066152);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fthloc).title("Certain Location"));
        float zoomLevel = (float) 10.0f;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(fthloc));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.036585, -114.066152), 18.0f));

    }
    protected void onLocationChanged(GoogleMap mMap, Location location) {
        LatLng urloc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(urloc).title("Your Location)"));
        float zoomLevel = (float) 10.0f;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(urloc));
    }

    private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting user's current location in this code?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, and have tried lots of different ways. I don't have the code yet. I'm asking how to do that and looking for ways that work.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial I think this will help you.

Comment: @GhulamMoinulQuadir Thanks. I already looked at that, but I don't know where to put it so that I can have both of my markers.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get location from one of my apps.

```
public class LocationProvider extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    //flag gor GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    //flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude; // Latitude
    double longitude; // Longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public LocationProvider(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        location = getLocation();
    }


    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // Getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // No network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    }catch (SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    //Log.d("NetworkLocation", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        try {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        } catch (SecurityException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                            if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                           // Log.i("LOC_Net:latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));
                           // Log.i("LOC_Net:langitude",String.valueOf(longitude));
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If GPS enabled, get latitude/longitude using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        try {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        } catch (SecurityException e){e.printStackTrace();}

                           // Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            try {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            } catch (SecurityException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                                if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app.
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            try{
            locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationProvider.this);
              }catch (SecurityException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    }


    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/Wi-Fi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }


    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog.
     * On pressing the Settings button it will launch Settings Options.
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Turn On Location");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Location is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
```

In your activity declare variables

private double latitude;
private double longitude;

and create a method like this:

```
private boolean getLocation(){

    locationProvider = new LocationProvider(this);
    Location location = locationProvider.getLocation();

    if (locationProvider.canGetLocation()){
        latitude = locationProvider.getLatitude();
        longitude = locationProvider.getLongitude();

        return true;

    } else {
        //Can't get location//GPS or network is not enabled
        //Ask user to enable GPS/Network in settings
        locationProvider.showSettingsAlert();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try. How can I use this and also keep my MapView with marker?

Comment: Create an object from this class and call getLocation() which returns a  Location object (from which you can get latitude and longitude). I haven't used markers in my app but I think you have to call one of the moveCamera() methods which requires latitude and longitude as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this, but it didn't work and crashed my app.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer with more detail. However, I can't quite get it to work. When I enter that into my activity, I get an error reading "onDestroy() in 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompactActivity' clashes with 'onDestroy()' in 'android.app.Service'; attempting to assign weaker privileges ('protected'); was public." The thing is, I don't have anything like that that is obvious. Could you please offer some advice?